# Securing part of a site with an existing cookie and no login controls

Tags: asp.net

I have a small web app, and a requirement is to secure only part of the site. To enter the main content, the user has two select a certain value from each of the two drop down boxes on the Default page and then agree to some Terms and Conditions. After this, they are redirected to a page with sensitive content.  This page with sensitive content is supposed to be secured, using an original cookie used throughout the site which prevents unauthorised access.

I'm ok with using forms authentication, but how can I go about securing part of a site without using anything like a login control?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need in other words is to secure part of the site without authenticating the user? If the sensitive content is accessible to anonymous users, then why secure it in the first place?

If however all you need is to have the user accept the Terms and Conditions in order to see the sensitive content, then you just have to save the cookie after the user accepts the terms and conditions, and then look for it in each page that presents the user with the sensitive content. If the user does not have the cookie, then redirect them to the Terms and Conditions page.

Answer (score 0):

For example Create a Folder called Secure.  Add a web.config to it with the following for authorization:

```
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Then one the page where you determine if they are allowed to have access, simply use:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),false)
```

This way, you do not care about what user name they use you only care they are authorized by your site.

Make sure you have the relevant forms tag in the main web.config of your site.

Hope this helps.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your page's or directories to be authenticated like that in your web.config :

```
<location path="MySensitiveDirectory">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(VS.71).aspx) about location element in web.config

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a login control, you can build your own FormsAuthenticationTicket in response to the user agreeing to your Terms and Conditions.

Some example code is here: http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/web/security/FormsAuthenticationTicketClass.aspx